# apex:inputField and Javascript

Tags: visualforce, javascript, html, custom, bind-variable

I am curious if there is a way to show/hide my `<apex:inputField>` once I start typing AND save the data to a custom object.

**Option 1:**
I am able to do this functionality with a `<input>` tag and javascript but I am unable to save the Stipulation_Reason__c value to a salesforce object.

```
<input id="textbox2" value="{!stipObj.Stipulation_Reason__c}" />

<div id="savebutton3" style="display:none">
   <apex:pageBlock >
      <apex:commandButton action="{!SaveStip}" value="Save"/>
   </apex:pageBlock>
</div>
--------------------------------------------------------------
$(function() {
$('#textbox2').on('keyup change', function() {
    if (this.value.length > 0) {
        $('#savebutton3').show();
    }
    else {
        $('#savebutton3').hide();
    }
});
});
```

**Option 2:**
I am able to save Stipulation_Reason__c to the custom Object but it is not responsive to the javascript

```
<apex:InputField id="textbox2maybe" value="{!stipObj.Stipulation_Reason__c}" />
```

Is it possible to use apex:inputField with JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<apex:inputField ... />` provides an attribute `onchange` it binds a JavaScript code to the field onchange event, in this attribute method you can add your JavaScript logic like:

```
<apex:InputField id="textbox2maybe" onchange="javascript:onStipulationReasonChange(this);" value="{!stipObj.Stipulation_Reason__c}" />

<script>
  function onStipulationReasonChange(el){
    if(el.value.length > 0){
      $('#savebutton3').show();
    }else{
      $('#savebutton3').hide();
    }
  }
</script>
```

You can also add `onkeyup` if only `onchange` doesn't work for you.

**UPDATE**

This works with `onkeyup` here is the code sample:

**test.vf**

```
<apex:page controller="Test">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:inputField value="{!con.LastName}" onkeyup="javascript:toggleIt(this);" />
        <div id="toggleIt" style="display:none;">
            <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}" />
        </div>
    </apex:form>

    <script>
    var item = document.getElementById('toggleIt');
    function toggleIt(el){
        console.log(el.value.length);
        item.style.display = ((el.value.length > 0)? 'block': 'none');
    }
    </script>

</apex:page>
```

**Test.apxc**

```
public class Test {

    public Contact con{get;set;}

    public Test(){
        con = new Contact(); 
    }

    public PageReference save(){
        insert con;
        return null;
    }    

}
```

Comment: The issue with onChange is that I have to click away from the input field or press enter for the save button to show up. I want the button to show up once I start typing.

Comment: Then try `onkeyup` instead of `onchange`, this should help you... :)

Comment: I actually marked this correct too soon. I forgot to check to see if the value was being saved, which it is not. When I don't use JS then I am able to bind the variable and save to the database with my simple APEX code (I just instantiate a new instance of the Stipulation__c object - stipObj). For some reason the JS is not allowing a save to happen. My thought is that I will have to do extra logic in apex to save the input value but I would like to avoid that if this is something that the binded variables should take care of themselves.

Comment: @Olivia, I have tested the variable binding and it's working fine as expected.

Answer (score 0):

If you viewed the source of the HTML on your Visualforce Page you would see that the Id gets changed a little when rendered.

For instance, if you set a `<apex:inputField>` with the parameter of `id="something"`, you find the HTML would be rendered something like: `j_id0:j_id2:j_id3:j_id4:j_id5:something`. Your JS may literally be looking for just `something`, not `j_id0:j_id2:j_id3:j_id4:j_id5:something`.

You can get around this by, in your JavaScript, using the $Component global merge field type. For example, your JS might look like:

```
$("#{!$Component.something}")
```

Rather than:

```
$("#something")
```

This would then render the correct Id in the JavaScript described in your Visualforce Page.

Comment: I think it only in case if you are using `id` with `apex tags`, not with `html` tags

Comment: @itzmukeshy7 That's correct. :)